# python-script does not load libraries when invoked by cron

Tags: python, pandas, bash, cron

I have a python-script that uses matplotlib and pandas to load and plot some data. The [python-script](https://hammeln.selfhost.eu/pi/plot_mean_error_by_hour.py) is not worth mentioning.

If a usual user (eg `pi`) starts this script, it does well. But soon as `cron` starts the same script, libraries such as pandas can not be loaded any more.

To gain some more information I wrapped the python-script in a [bash-script](https://hammeln.selfhost.eu/pi/plot_mean_error_by_hour.bash). I have checked `env` (including `PATH`) and they seem to be the same for `cron` and `pi`. As long as usual user `pi` starts the script, it looks well:

```
Start plot_mean_error_by_hour.bash
SHELL=/bin/bash
LANGUAGE=de_DE.UTF-8
NO_AT_BRIDGE=1
PWD=/home/pi/public_html
LOGNAME=pi
XDG_SESSION_TYPE=tty
HOME=/home/pi
LANG=de_DE.UTF-8
LS_COLORS=rs=0: ... :*.xspf=00;36:
SSH_CONNECTION=192.168.178.20 51164 192.168.178.40 22
XDG_SESSION_CLASS=user
TERM=xterm-256color
USER=pi
DISPLAY=localhost:10.0
SHLVL=2
XDG_SESSION_ID=40005
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000
SSH_CLIENT=192.168.178.20 51164 22
LC_ALL=de_DE.UTF-8
PATH=.:/:/usr/bin/python3:/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages:/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/home/pi/public_html:/home/pi/public_html/plot_mean_error_by_hour.bash
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus
MAIL=/var/mail/pi
SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/0
OLDPWD=/home/pi
TEXTDOMAIN=Linux-PAM
_=/usr/bin/env
got pandas from ['/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas']
can read /home/pi/public_html/testprovider.hdf
read /home/pi/public_html/testprovider.hdf
...
labeled plot
wrote /home/pi/public_html/testprovider.svg
```

But when `cron` uses the same bash-script python fails loading its libraries:

```
Start plot_mean_error_by_hour.bash
SHELL=/bin/bash
LANGUAGE=de_DE.UTF-8
PWD=/home/pi
LOGNAME=pi
HOME=/home/pi
LANG=de_DE.UTF-8
SHLVL=1
LC_ALL=de_DE.UTF-8
PATH=.:/:/usr/bin/python3:/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages:/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/home/pi/public_html:/home/pi/public_html/plot_mean_error_by_hour.bash
_=/usr/bin/env
```

Both `PATH`- and `SHELL`-variables are just the same and I like to get some more information why python launched by `cron` fails. How can I get more information?

Thanx for any hint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silly me! [source](https://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/sourceh.html) just did the trick. Added `source /home/pi/.bashrc` to the bash-script and python does load it all as supposed.